# add 1 to every number in the list

Tags: list, replace, numbers, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver I have a long list, which looks like this:

```
.classname li:nth-of-type(1) {...}
.classname li:nth-of-type(23) {...}
.classname li:nth-of-type(111) {...}
```

And so on.
What I need to do now is to add 1 to every li:nth-of-type selector, so it becomes:

```
.classname li:nth-of-type(2) {...}
.classname li:nth-of-type(24) {...}
.classname li:nth-of-type(112) {...}
```

I tried to accomplish this via the search and replace function via regex, which did not work because of the addition.

What would be easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way that I'm aware of to perform the operation you're asking for.Y ou will have to do the changes manually within Dreamweaver.

I you are good at JavaScript though, you may be able to use Tom Muck's Evaluate JavaScript panel ( http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=270FB commercial, but only $2 I've not tired it in CS5.5 or 6, but it for sure worked in CS5, and should work in later versions), or the Dreamweaver Platform SDK ( http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1009962# while it says DW8 and MX2004 it should work in later versions, I'm sure I had it installed into CS3, and just tested in CS6 and it installed fine, just a small issue where a couple of the added menu items get placed onto a Commands -> Miscellaneous menu ) which includes a command that you can enter JavaScript into and run.

So, why mention JavaScript here? Well, Dreamweaver's extensibility layer is built exposing a JavaScript API. This means that you can manipulate documents with JavaScript. In this case, edit the document to increment the numbers.

I just tested the following in Dreamweaver CS6 using the Dreamweaver Platform SDK Evaluate JavaScript command.

Select in code view the CSS selectors you want to increment.
Go to Commands -> SDK Tools -> Evaluate JavaScript.
Paste the code that follows into your document:

```
var dom = dw.getDocumentDOM();
var sel = dom.source.getSelection();
var src = dom.source.getText(sel[0], sel[1]);

var matches = src.match(/(\.classname li:nth-of-type\()(\d+)(\))/g);
var newSrc = src;
if(matches){
    for(var i =0; i< matches.length; i++){
      // note: the following code through the ending ; is all on one line
      newSrc = newSrc.replace( matches[i], matches[i].replace(/(\.classname li:nth-of-type\()(\d+)(\))/, function(str, p1, p2, p3){return p1 + (parseInt(p2)+1) + p3} ) );
    }
}

dom.source.replaceRange(sel[0], sel[1], newSrc);
```

Click the Eval button. You should see the numbers incremented in the code.

Note: This code uses regular expressions to find the specific CSS selectors you provided, so if you have different CSS selectors, you'd need to adjust the RegExp on the src.match() line, as well as within the newSrc.replace() lines.

To make it a little more generic, you may want to try something like the following:

```
var dom = dw.getDocumentDOM();
var sel = dom.source.getSelection();
var src = dom.source.getText(sel[0], sel[1]);

var matches = src.match(/(\()(\d+)(\))/g);
var newSrc = src;
if(matches){
    for(var i =0; i< matches.length; i++){
        // note: the following code through the ending ; is all on one line
        newSrc = newSrc.replace( matches[i], matches[i].replace(/(\()(\d+)(\))/, function(str, p1, p2, p3){return p1 + (parseInt(p2)+1) + p3} ) );
    }
}

dom.source.replaceRange(sel[0], sel[1], newSrc);
```

This simply replaces any text that matches a number wrapped by parentheses.